# drawPaint and drawText in a customView

Tags: android, android-custom-view, ondraw, custom-view

I don't understand the difference between the two methods `drawPaint` and `drawText` ? If I want to define how a customed `TextView`, and that I want to define its own `Typeface` and `TextColor`: do I have to define a `textPaint` object then use methods like `setTypeface` and `setColor` then call `drawPaint` on `onDraw` method on my canvas or do I have to call directly `drawText` ?

Comment: did you read the documentation for drawPaint and drawText?

Comment: what does drawPaint have to do with drawText ?

Comment: In this documentation http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html it said that a Paint objectn should defined in order to define how the object should be defined.

Comment: I use drawText in order to draw the text of my custom View